# Jquery Datatable Infinite Scroll (Horizontal)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have an datatable an many columns (it can be more than 30) and if there are more than 10 columns , datatable is taking columns to bottom of the row but I want to show all of columns in the same row and without taking to bottom of the row.

I tried scrollx,bScrollInfinite etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just solved it, there is a problem that : if you use **responsive:true** datatable is taking all of columns after 10.column to bottom of the the row.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery datatable have `scrollX` property that make the `X` axis scrolling if the contents are more than the width of the container. Use it like:

```
scrollX : true,
```

[Reference](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_x.html)

Comment: I have still been using this but datatable is still taking many columns to bottom of the row.

Comment: Create a demo kind of jsfiddle with your dataset and share the jsfiddle link